# How to Load all .yaml files in directory using Spring/Jackson

Tags: java, spring, yaml

I want to load in a collection of .yaml files that each specify an object in a list. I know how to read in a specific file and parse it using jackson, as follows:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory());

MicroServiceObject object = mapper.readValue(new File("src/main/resources/microservices/retrieveAccount.yaml"), MicroServiceObject.class);
```

however i'd like to read in all the files in the `microservices` directory and add them to my database/list.

How can I read in/iterate over all the files in a specific directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`File#listFiles`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles(java.io.FileFilter)) can give you a list of files (in form of an `array`) in a directory:

```
File directory = new File("src/main/resources/microservices")
File[] files = directory.listFiles((pathname) -> pathname.getName().endsWith(".yaml"));
```

Comment: thanks, but listFiles returns a File[] not a list. I tried the code above and got an incompatible type error.

Answer (score 1):

Another way using a DirectoryStream could be

```
private void loadConfig() {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory())
        Path dir = Paths.get("src/main/resources/microservices");
        // creates a stream of every file in the directory. Filters by if they have the extension .yml or .yaml
        try (DirectoryStream<Path> stream = Files.newDirectoryStream(dir, "*.{yml,yaml}")) {
            for (Path file : stream) {
                // map the object from a file in the directory
                MicroServiceObject object = mapper.readValue(file.toFile(), MicroServiceObject.class);
                // do what ever you need to with the read in config
            }
        } catch (IOException | DirectoryIteratorException x) {
            // Handle your errors here for loading in configurations
            System.err.println(x);
        }
    }
```

src: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/dirs.html

Comment: Did you test this? I think this won't work with the path specified.